# New Frame function fails to size the new frame correctly and prints a Gtk-CRITICAL message. Is this the return of an old bug?

Tags: linux, upgrade

I am using Emacs 29.1. After upgrading Linux to Ubuntu 23.04 the emacs create new frame function (C-x 5 2) seems broken.
What happens: when I create a new frame, it shows up so tiny (15x7) that the GTK widget can't fit all the menu bar items and throws the following error:

(emacs:11091): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:28:07.823: gtk_distribute_natural_allocation: assertion 'extra_space >= 0' failed

I have been trying to modify init.el to try and *force* the new frame to be bigger unsuccessfully. But probably I won't be able to force it because this problem happens even when I run with 'emacs -Q'. Which makes me think there's some kind of basic incompatibility introduced with the Ubuntu upgrade.

Have any of you seen this? Any ideas?

I use X11 - X.Org version: 1.22.1.8

I added no extra flags to the emacs compilation -it was vanilla. The compilation config.log doesn't show support for non-X window managers as far as I can tell. Also, config.log indicates emacs was compiled with gtk-3.0

When launching emacs, the initial window displays the correct size, and the Messages buffer is clean.

Comment: If you don't get an answer that explains this and why it should be expected, consider `M-x report-emacs-bug'.

Comment: Please also indicate in the question whether you are using Wayland or X and whether you have compiled emacs to support non-X window managers?

Comment: X.Org version: 1.22.1.8; I added no extra flags to the compilation -it was vanilla. The config.log doesn't show support non-X window managers as far as I can tell. But not being an expert, I can't decipher most the contents in config.log

Comment: I am seeing the same problem on current Debian testing in all GNOME sessions (but not with fvwm).

Comment: Confirming same iissue with default Emacs 28.2 (as shipped) under Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: I filed emacs bug #65559. Turns out there's some incompatibility between emacs and the Wayland windows manager (default in many distros).